# XML configuration of Zend_Form: child nodes and attributes not always equal?

Tags: zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-config-xml

A set of forms (using Zend_Form) that I have been working on were causing me some headaches trying to figure out what was wrong with my XML configuration, as I kept getting unexpected HTML output for a particular INPUT element. It was supposed to be getting a default value, but nothing appeared.

It appears that the following 2 pieces of XML are not equal when used to instantiate Zend_Form:

Snippet #1:

```
<form>
  <elements>
    <test type="hidden">
      <options ignore="true" value="foo"/>
    </test>
  </elements>
</form>
```

Snippet #2:

```
<form>
  <elements>
    <test type="hidden">
      <options ignore="true">
        <value>foo</value>
      </options>
    </test>
  </elements>
</form>
```

The type of the element doesn't appear to make a difference, so it doesn't appear to be related to hidden fields.

Is this expected or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was rather quiet on here, I took a look further into the source code and documentation.

On line 259 of Zend_Config_Xml, the SimpleXMLElement object attributes are converted to a string, resulting in:

```
options Object of: SimpleXMLElement 
    @attributes Array [2]   
        label   (string:7) I can't see this because 
        value   (string:21) something happens to this
```

becoming

```
options (string:21) something happens to this
```

So, I hunted through the documentation only to find that "value" is a reserved keyword when used as an attribute in an XML file that is loaded into Zend_Config_Xml:

> [Example #2 Using Tag Attributes in Zend_Config_Xml](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.xml.html)
>
> "..Zend_Config_Xml also supports two
> additional ways of defining nodes in
> the configuration. Both make use of
> attributes. Since the extends and the
> value attributes are reserved keywords
> (the latter one by the second way of
> using attributes), they may not be
> used..."

Thus, it would appear to be "expected" according to the documentation.
I'm not entirely happy that this is a good idea though, considering "value" is an attribute of form elements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about this. The reserved keywords were moved to their own namespace, and the previous attributes were depricated. In Zend Framework 2.0 the non-namespaced attributes will be removed so you can use them again.